# String.split with ** crashes

Tags: java, string, split, crash

I come across a very strange problem when doing a split on a String.
The second line of the code below crashes:

```
String[] parts1 = "2 xy 3".split("xy"); //OK!
String[] parts2 = "2 ** 3".split("**"); //CRASHES java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1: **
```

Comment: it's because it's a reserved character, and so you need to escape it with \\ [double backslash])

Comment: @jbutler483 Actually, it's a meta character for a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Oh, ok. I just thought it was multiplication (I haven't used it for anything else before)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] parts2 = "2 ** 3".split("\\*\\*");
```

The problem is that the `*` has a special meaning in regex patterns, so the workaround is to use double-slash(since single slash would demand an escape character) before a `*`

For more info on how regex works in java, probably [my slide](http://www.slideshare.net/OblivionWalker/regular-expressions-in-java-29682344) on SlideShare would be useful.

Comment: To be more precise we need double backslash here because backslash is special character in String (it can be used to create line separator `\n` for instance) so to create String literal ``\`` and pass it to regex engine we need to escape it with another ``\``. In other words string representing ``\`` literal needs to be written as `"\\"`. BUT to avoid this confusion we can use `[ ]` (character class, also called character set) to escape some of regex metacharacters like `*`, so we could just write `split("[*][*]");`

Comment: @Pshemo i didn't knew that workaround, thanks for the knowledge :)